# Как установить клавиатурный фокус в Control в окне Avalonia?

Tags: c#, avalonia

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нарисовал окно, но когда оно отображается во время выполнения, клавиатурный фокус не в поле ввода, т.е. работая в таком приложении и вызывая окно, пользователь должен сначала тупо нажимать Tab, а потом вводить текст. Вообще, наблюдая за окнами в Avalonia я обнаружил такое состояние окна, когда вокус ввода с клавиатуры на форме установлен "в никуда".

Как это поправить? Возможно, это выглядит несущественно - подумаешь, лишнее нажатие, но в приложении, которое я делаю (поясню - приложение по лингвистике и переводам, в возникающем окне нужно будет выбрать нужный вариант смысла слова, правда там будет AutoCompleteBox, но зазубрина та же самая), за один сеанс нужно будет одно и тоже окно с разными вариантами открыть 1000 и более раз, и такое 1000-разовое, при этом абсолютно чоповое, ненужное нажатие клавиши Tab будет только тормозить рабочий процесс и сбивать с мысли.

AXAML:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="SpaceDunyal.Forms.Window1"
        Title="Window1">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <TextBox Name="MyInput" Watermark="Введите текст"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using Avalonia.Controls;

namespace SpaceDunyal.Forms
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyInput.Focus(); // Без эффекта
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Всё равно не работает_ - ну тогда я сдаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше после загрузки окна поставить фокус типа

```
public async void load(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => this.blabla.Focus());
    await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => this.blabla.SelectAll());
}
```

Comment: Оставляйте более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].